# syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or )

Tags: go

I get error syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or ). im new at golang. im try with new code but same error. can someone help me?.
my code

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "html/template"
import "path"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var filepath = path.Join("index.html")
        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        
  http.HandleFunc("/membuat-web-dengan-golang", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var filepath = path.Join("membuat-web-dengan-golang.html")
        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))

    fmt.Println("server started at localhost:9000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You are missing closing `}` for the anonymous functions and  the closing ')' for the calls to http.HandleFunc.  Add `})` at line 15 and 23.  See fix [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Uz3Gtm7S4H2).   Also, you should add code to use the parsed templates.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your HandleFunc functions are missing the closing brackets. Check the fmt.Println(tmpl) line which I added to your code. The first closing curly bracket `}` is for the anonymous function and the second round bracket `)` is for the HandleFunc.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var filepath = path.Join("index.html")
        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    fmt.Println(tmpl)})
        
  http.HandleFunc("/membuat-web-dengan-golang", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var filepath = path.Join("membuat-web-dengan-golang.html")
        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    fmt.Println(tmpl)})
        
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))

    fmt.Println("server started at localhost:9000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```